Gitlab CI scheduled pipelines message overwrite
I have a pipeline in GitLab that can be triggered from both commits and schedules. It is functioning correctly, but I've noticed that scheduled pipelines consistently show "Created by: [my name]" and the pipeline name/message corresponds to the message of the latest commit on the branch.
Is there a way to override these values for scheduled pipelines? I want to customize the "Created by" field and provide a separate name/message for scheduled pipelines.
I have searched through the GitLab UI for any options to configure these parameters, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

it would be helpful to see the relevant pipeline code

It's just a maven build with dependency scanning, Sonarqube a Artifactory upload. Nothing fancy. The schedule is completely configured in the Gitlab UI.
